# Не могу понять принцип работы поиска простых чисел

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, простые-числа

Объясните, пожалуйста построчно, зачем нужен тот или иной участок строки? По какому принципу в данном случае используются индексы списка, срезы и бинарное И?

```py
def primes2(n):
    """ Input n>=6, Returns a list of primes, 2 <= p < n """
    n, correction = n - n%6 + 6, 2 - (n%6 > 1)
    sieve = [True] * (n//3)
    for i in range(1, int(n**0.5)//3 + 1):
        if sieve[i]:
            k=3*i + 1|1
            sieve[k*k//3::2*k] = [False] * ((n//6-k*k//6-1)//k+1)
            sieve[k*(k-2*(i&1)+4)//3::2*k] = [False] * ((n//6-k*(k-2*(i&1)+4)//6-1)//k+1)
    return [2,3] + [3*i + 1|1 for i in range(1, n//3-correction) if sieve[i]]
```

ps Взято из https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035188/9624362

Comment: индексы - это предыдущие просты числа. если число не делится на простое, то оно и не делится на любое другое.

Answer (score 0):

Вот первый вариант:

```
a=int(input("до \n"))
s = [2]
for x in range(3,a,2): #возьмем 1,3,5,7,9,11,13............
    k=0
    for n in s:
        if x%s[k]==0:
            break
        elif s[k]==s[-1]:
                s.append(x)
                break
        else:
            k+=1
print(s[:])
```

Второй вариант:

```
s=[2]
for x in range(3,int(input("до \n")),2): #возьмем 1,3,5,7,9,11,13............
    k=(x%i for i in s)
    if 0 not in k: 
        s.append(x) 
print(s[:])
```